# I want to know how to sort a list of dictionaries, where the dictionary has a dictionary within it

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

So if I have 3 dictionaries:

```
dictionary = {'id':879, 'data':{'price': 18.90, 'location':'london', 'zipcode':'ha30ds'}}

dictionary2 = {'id':871, 'data':{'price': 24.00, 'location':'paris', 'zipcode':'nw93uo'}}

dictionary3 = {'id':873, 'data':{'price': 17.00, 'paris':'london', 'zipcode':'nw34kh'}}
```

and put them in a list:

```
list = [dictionary,dictionary2,dictionary3]
```

where

```
list[0]['data']['price'] == 18.90
```

I want to sort this list of dictionaries by price....
I tried this:

```
newlist = sorted(list, key=['lambda'] k: k['data']['price'])
```

but this doesn't work....any ideas?

Comment: `sorted(list, key=lambda k: k['data']['price']) `

Comment: amazing thank you! this returns it in the order of data first with location, price then zipcode, and then id at the end.... do you know how i would keep the order of the keys the same